# python - matplotlib - Showing all x axis labels even if bar length is zero

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame that shows the count of occurencies by month, but only the months between 5 (May) and 11 (November) is present, the others are unoccupied.

I still want to show the other months, even if the bar length is zero.

I have tried:

```
df_grouped = df.departureDate.groupby(df['departureDate'].dt.month).count()

f, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,5))

ax1.bar(range(len(df_grouped)), df_grouped, alpha=0.5, color='b')

ax1.set_xticks(pd.np.arange(0, 12, 1))
```

When adding the last line I get x label from all the months, but the months are not mapped correctly to the x label. The month of May starts at 1 and not at 5, and the month of November ends at 6, while the rest of the empty x labes continue until 12.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nob9I.png)

[Final plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfILy.png)

[Desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJS6N.png)

Comment: I think you should give the desired plot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are plotting, you are using `range(len(df_grouped))` for x axis. This assigns values of 0-6 for the x-axis causing the issue. You should be assigning the month column to x-axis. As you have not provided the data, I am creating dummy data to show the change required. See if this what you are looking for.

```
## My dummy data
df_grouped=pd.DataFrame({'Val':[0.1, 0.05, 1.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1], 'month':[5,6,7,8,9,10,11]})
f, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,5))
ax1.bar(df_grouped['month'], df_grouped['Val'], alpha=0.5, color='b') ##Using month as x-axis values

ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 13, 1))
```

[image]